# Do I need to Free() a TDateTime?

Tags: delphi

It seems to be working, but I am scratching my head trying to find a memory leak and I am not very good at that sort thing :-(

```
const UNIX_START_DATE: TDateTime = 25569.0;

function UnixToDateTime(USec: Longint): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := (Usec / 86400) + UNIX_START_DATE;
end;
```

I am not actually calling `TDateTime.Create()` - but is the compiler (meaning that I would have to free it soemwhere)?  Or, since `TDateTime` is bascially just a douuble, is the compiler just pushing it on the stack for assignment to the caller?

Comment: More likely something else with a TDateTime field is leaking

Comment: "TDateTime is bascially just a double" - that is the answer. It is "double" and you should treat it like you treat "double". BTW, if you did not somethign werid, then you just CANNOT free it. Does `UNIX_START_DATE.Free` even compile?

Comment: +1 @Arioch'The - yes, it compiles, runs and does what it ought to. I am just clutching at straws here, trying to find a leak.  I wouldn't even ask about this except that TDateTime has a constructor (I didn't check - does double?)  I am narrowing down an out of memory exception over a long time and that fn() gets called regularly on timer expiry. I just wondered.

Comment: it has a constructor ? which delphi version u have ? what is that code with constructor ? BTW, it would be generally nice to press "retag" link and add delphi version tag to the question

Comment: if u suspense this function to leak - just run it alone zillion of times and see if it does. Or open CPU windows and read machine code that it turns into - does it ever allocate memory or not :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing to free. `TDateTime` is a simple type based on `Double` and as such it's not allocated on the heap.

Comment: Nitpick: they can be allocated on the heap with `New` or `GetMem`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `PDateTime` sure, like any other pointer type, obviously. I didn't think this was the topic here.

Comment: Just to list a few more types similar to `TDateTime` which don't require creation/destruction, `TTime`, `TCaption`, `THandle`, `TNotifyEvent`, `TRtlCriticalSection`, etc. Some are used as pointers, and therefore require creation/destruction by means outside the standard outside interface. For example, creating a Windows canvas handle and freeing it. The only thing which can be created is some sort of class (or object), and in later versions of Delphi, in records.